# Oracle SQL Developer - errors copying a view from one database to another

Tags: database, oracle, view, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to copy a view from one database to another. I'm exporting the view using 'Quick DDL > save to worksheet' to generate the script. At the top of the script i get the message:

```
"-- Unable to render VIEW DDL for object <view name> with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal generator."
```

Both the databases are identical, the view I'm trying to copy existed in both databases but was dropped in error in one of them.

When I try to run the script on my second database i get the error

Error report:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-00001: unique constraint (SYS.I_COL1) violated
00604. 00000 -  "error occurred at recursive SQL level %s"
*Cause:    An error occurred while processing a recursive SQL statement
           (a statement applying to internal dictionary tables).
*Action:   If the situation described in the next error on the stack
           can be corrected, do so; otherwise contact Oracle Support.
```

Has anyone any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: how you are copying the view. your error seems not related with view creation

Comment: Hi, Im using the Quick DDL > Save to worksheet to generate a script and just running that script on the second database. I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: you're using SQL Developer - be sure to state that explicitly so folks know what you're doing. You are stating 2 problems, unable to get the script, but then also an error when running said script. You might have a privilege issue on the first one, get a DBA to grant you higher data dictionary privs as running DBMS_METADATA package against schema objects in different schemas requires some 'power'. The 2nd error message kinda sounds like the data dictionary is corrupt - like the database thinks the view or parts of it are still there.

Comment: Yup, I'm using sql developer. I've updated the question to reflect this. So I raised the issue with my DBA and he's confirmed that the issue was to do with my privileges. As for the second error message I can't comment as the issue is with my DBA now. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The message

> -- Unable to render VIEW DDL for object  with DBMS_METADATA attempting internal

gives the SQL Developer.
This is due to the fact that he can not use dbms_metadata.get_ddl.
If everything is fine with the privileges, most likely due to the type of error (on execute dbms_metadata.get_ddl):

```
 ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
 LPX-00210: expected '<' instead of 'n'
 ORA-06512: at "SYS.UTL_XML", line 0
 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA_INT", line 3296
 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA_INT", line 4148
 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 458
 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 615
 ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 1221
 ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Try to reload the XML API:

```
1. enable restricted database session
2. run:
(from $ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/admin):
catnomet.sql
rmxml.sql
to remove the xml subsystem and after that: catxml
utlcxml.sql
prvtcxml.plb
catmet.sql
to reload it.
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the problem was because in the view there were two columns with the same name or alias, and since the COL $ table has a unique index with the object number, and the name of the column, two columns are not allowed with the same name